# R how to import a list with different number of columns to a data frame

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, scopus

I am trying to perform some scientometrics analysis from a Scopus csv file. The first column of the imported csv is like:

```
Authors,Title,Year,Source title,Volume,Issue,Art. No.,Page start,Page end,Page count,Cited by,DOI,Link,Document Type,Source,EID
"Kuck, L.S., Noreña, C.P.Z.","Microencapsulation of grape (Vitis labrusca var. Bordo) skin phenolic extract using gum Arabic, polydextrose, and partially hydrolyzed guar gum as encapsulating agents",2016,"Food Chemistry","194",,,"569","576",,,10.1016/j.foodchem.2015.08.066,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84940212199&partnerID=40&md5=e4c36e03156570a7fe31c2937b3a170d",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84940212199
"Grasel, F.D.S., Ferrão, M.F., Wolf, C.R.","Development of methodology for identification the nature of the polyphenolic extracts by FTIR associated with multivariate analysis",2016,"Spectrochimica Acta - Part A: Molecular and Biomolecular Spectroscopy","153",,,"94","101",,,10.1016/j.saa.2015.08.020,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84939865445&partnerID=40&md5=8239487f4eea9479d698792e6aa348de",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84939865445
"De Souza, D., Sbardelotto, A.F., Ziegler, D.R., Marczak, L.D.F., Tessaro, I.C.","Characterization of rice starch and protein obtained by a fast alkaline extraction method",2016,"Food Chemistry","191",, 17279,"36","44",,,10.1016/j.foodchem.2015.03.032,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84938952690&partnerID=40&md5=989cbfcc72286a87f726925732db4b49",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84938952690
"Filho, P.R.M., Vercelino, R., Cioato, S.G., Medeiros, L.F., de Oliveira, C., Scarabelot, V.L., Souza, A., Rozisky, J.R., Quevedo, A.S., Adachi, L.N.S., Sanches, P.R.S., Fregni, F., Caumo, W., Torres, I.L.S.","Transcranial direct current stimulation (tDCS) reverts behavioral alterations and brainstem BDNF level increase induced by neuropathic pain model: Long-lasting effect",2016,"Progress in Neuro-Psychopharmacology and Biological Psychiatry","64",,,"44","51",,,10.1016/j.pnpbp.2015.06.016,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84937468588&partnerID=40&md5=b03f0ccfbf66a49a438c9983cc2e8f9d",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84937468588
"Duarte, Á.T., Borges, A.R., Zmozinski, A.V., Dessuy, M.B., Welz, B., De Andrade, J.B., Vale, M.G.R.","Determination of lead in biomass and products of the pyrolysis process by direct solid or liquid sample analysis using HR-CS GF AAS",2016,"Talanta","146",,,"166","174",,,10.1016/j.talanta.2015.08.041,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84940416990&partnerID=40&md5=55d7ddad27e955b9b6e269469e29c8c3",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84940416990
"Francischini, H., Paes Neto, V.D., Martinelli, A.G., Pereira, V.P., Marinho, T.S., Teixeira, V.P.A., Ferraz, M.L.F., Soares, M.B., Schultz, C.L.","Invertebrate traces in pseudo-coprolites from the upper Cretaceous Marília Formation (Bauru Group), Minas Gerais State, Brazil",2016,"Cretaceous Research","57",,,"29","39",,,10.1016/j.cretres.2015.07.016,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84939175950&partnerID=40&md5=b049de15a08ba477cc189d7e8fe7f0a3",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84939175950
"Bonfatti, B.R., Hartemink, A.E., Giasson, E., Tornquist, C.G., Adhikari, K.","Digital mapping of soil carbon in a viticultural region of Southern Brazil",2016,"Geoderma","261",,,"204","221",,,10.1016/j.geoderma.2015.07.016,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84939499978&partnerID=40&md5=b470166e01648dcbe8f0d43be86c84e0",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84939499978
"Scaramuzza dos Santos, T.C., Holanda, E.C., de Souza, V., Guerra-Sommer, M., Manfroi, J., Uhl, D., Jasper, A.","Evidence of palaeo-wildfire from the upper Lower Cretaceous (Serra do Tucano Formation, Aptian-Albian) of Roraima (North Brazil)",2016,"Cretaceous Research","57",,,"46","49",,,10.1016/j.cretres.2015.08.003,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84939615367&partnerID=40&md5=e59f5130c6a2e1863f9aa77c960e6462",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84939615367
"da Silva, S.W., Bortolozzi, J.P., Banús, E.D., Bernardes, A.M., Ulla, M.A.","TiO<inf>2</inf> thick films supported on stainless steel foams and their photoactivity in the nonylphenol ethoxylate mineralization",2016,"Chemical Engineering Journal","283",, 14049,"1264","1272",,,10.1016/j.cej.2015.08.057,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84940747062&partnerID=40&md5=aebc7357f9dedaadeebabfeda4aa3dd9",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84940747062
"Dalmora, A.C., Ramos, C.G., Oliveira, M.L.S., Teixeira, E.C., Kautzmann, R.M., Taffarel, S.R., de Brum, I.A.S., Silva, L.F.O.","Chemical characterization, nano-particle mineralogy and particle size distribution of basalt dust wastes",2016,"Science of the Total Environment","539",, 18331,"560","565",,,10.1016/j.scitotenv.2015.08.141,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84941754626&partnerID=40&md5=1c4ca1a3486ff55f92f238083af3eb50",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84941754626
"Fink, J.R., Inda, A.V., Bavaresco, J., Barrón, V., Torrent, J., Bayer, C.","Adsorption and desorption of phosphorus in subtropical soils as affected by management system and mineralogy",2016,"Soil and Tillage Research","155",,,"62","68",,,10.1016/j.still.2015.07.017,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84940195225&partnerID=40&md5=2e43a874f1e36f11aa5efa057ce660b9",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84940195225
"Martins, A.B., Santana, R.M.C.","Effect of carboxylic acids as compatibilizer agent on mechanical properties of thermoplastic starch and polypropylene blends",2016,"Carbohydrate Polymers","135",,,"79","85",,,10.1016/j.carbpol.2015.08.074,"http://www.scopus.com/inward/record.url?eid=2-s2.0-84940781718&partnerID=40&md5=426e62c6c0de33a91bdb2f75442fbd6f",Article,Scopus,2-s2.0-84940781718
```

In each line, there are a variable number of authors (up to more than 20). Until now, I am doing something like:

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv")
test$Authors <- as.character(test$Authors)
test2 <- strsplit(as.character(test$Authors), '.,', fixed=TRUE)
```

Which gives me a list correctly separating each author. I tested several alternatives proposed in the list to move the list to a data frame, but the closer one was:

```
test3 <- str_split_fixed(test$Authors, '.,', n = 20)
```

Which gave me two problems:

1) I have to define the number of columns, which I do not know before analyzing the data;
2) the authors are not properly separated, but surname and abbreviated names are in different columns. Additionally, the command removed some characters from the names.

Some of the strategies suggested elsewhere gave me the correct separation of authors in columns, but the empty columns were fulfilled by repeating the initial names. Sorry if the question is too naive, I am beginning in the use of R.

Any advises and or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your description / sample of the data is not good enough to work. We need the structure of the file you are reading. `test <- read.csv("test.csv")` won't work with the data provided above.

Comment: Please state clearly, what format you want to achieve for your data. Why is `strsplit` not doing what you want? It is basically the same as `str_split_fixed` without the need to give a fixed value for `n`.

Comment: I tried to simplify the information, and the sample became not representative, sorry about that. I pasted a small version of the sample, with the same format I am using.

Comment: I used the strsplit, and do obtained a list with the authors properly separated. However, I was not able to move this list properly to a data frame, as surnames and abbreviated names appeared in different columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

Firstly, using `read.csv` is causing the split between Authors last name and initial, so I'm using `readLines` instead.

Secondly, having "wide data" like this is not in general a good idea. It makes data more difficult to work with in subsequent analyses. For that reason, I've made it "long" instead.

```
n1 <- readLines(con="test.csv")
n1 <- strsplit(n1, '., ', fixed=TRUE)
n1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(n1), function(x){data.frame(aut = n1[[x]], pub = x, order = 1:length(n1[[x]]))}))
n1$aut <- gsub("\\.$", "", n1$aut)
```

Here's the output:

```
               aut pub order
1        Kuck, L.S   1     1
2   NoreÃ±a, C.P.Z   1     2
3    Grasel, F.D.S   2     1
4     FerrÃ£o, M.F   2     2
5        Wolf, C.R   2     3
6       Abreu, M.S   3     1
7 Giacomini, A.C.V   3     2
8         Gusso, D   3     3
9      Rosa, J.G.S   3     4
```

NB if you really want your data in "wide format", we can easily reshape it:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(n1, order, aut)

  pub             1                2         3           4
1   1     Kuck, L.S   NoreÃ±a, C.P.Z      <NA>        <NA>
2   2 Grasel, F.D.S     FerrÃ£o, M.F Wolf, C.R        <NA>
3   3    Abreu, M.S Giacomini, A.C.V  Gusso, D Rosa, J.G.S
```

EDIT: for your full version, you need to use `read.csv`:

```
input <- n1 <- read.csv("test.csv")
n1$Authors <- as.character(n1$Authors)
n1$Authors <- strsplit(n1$Authors, '., ', fixed=TRUE)
n1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(n1$Authors), function(x){data.frame(aut = n1$Authors[[x]], pub = x, order = 1:length(n1$Authors[[x]]))}))
n1$aut <- gsub("\\.$", "", n1$aut)
```

If you want to go back to wide with all your stuff:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
input <- mutate(input, row = row_number())
n1 %>% spread(order, aut) %>%
       left_join(input, by = c("pub" = "row")) %>%
       select(-Authors)
```

Comment: Great, it did work! And thanks for the advice in the data organization. But initially I would like to retain the proper wide format, to associate it with the remaining information from the reference. In this case, using your suggestion with the real sample (sorry about the too simplified version, I changed for the real one above), the rest of the reference information remains attached to the last author, in the last column. Do you have any hint in how to avoid that?

Comment: Just to perhaps make this more simple, I do not need to retain the information beyond the last authors in this moment, so it may be removed

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much for the help!